# How can you retrieve key of a datastore Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created datastore entity like below.  I am trying to get the key of the entity by looping the query result. Also Is this the right way to get key of an entity?

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity e = new Entity("User");
e.setProperty("userName", user.getUserName());
e.setProperty("email", user.getEmail());
ds.put(e);

Query q = new Query("User")
PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
Iterable<Entity> entityList = pq.asIterable();
for (Entity result : entityList) {
//how to get entity key from here
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why a -1 rating for the question. Is there anything wrong with the question. Then you can say so.I am just a newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a string representation of a key, you can do:

```
Key key = ds.put(e);
String keyString = KeyFactory.keyToString(key);
```

Comment: Thanks man. Thats exactly what I am looking for. So in the loop I can give `String userKey = KeyFactory.keyToString(result.getKey());` Marking as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
for (Entity result : entityList) {
   Key userKey = result.getKey();
}
```

Comment: Also, if you only need keys, you can set this query to be keys-only.

Comment: @svpino, the userKey value that I get is   _User(53)_.'What I wanted is the datastore key. Something like this **ag5pYnNjbG91ZHNlcnZlcnINCxIHUHJvZHVjdBgTDA** I tried this 'result.getKey().getId();' but not getting the key.

Comment: Check out this link for the list of methods of the Key class: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key

Comment: No, couldnt get Any Answer Yet. @AndreiVolgin, I tried with keys-only, but not getting what i wanted.